# Moment.js with 15 hours timelag

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

using a very simple moment.js function:

```
return moment.utc(data,  "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();
```

with this sample data: `"2013-10-23T14:45:33.397Z"` (utc)

for some reason, for data created just now, it shows me:

`15 hours ago`

Instead for :"a few seconds" ago, or something similiar.. if I remove the ``utc method```, the lag grows to 18. since my timezone is utc+3 this is logical, but the other 15 hours aren't..

Maybe this has something to do with timezone. but couldn't figure it out

I'll be glad for help with this!

Answer (score 4):

Your telling moment that the incoming sample data fits YYYYMMDD, i.e. 20131023.  With the ISO date string you can just do:

```
return moment.utc(data).fromNow()
```

Comment: thanks! this look to be in the right direction, but now I've got the opposite problem,  strangely enough this is true even if I remove the utc, looks like the date is being parsed wrongly

Comment: If you wanted it to handle explicitly the sample data, you'd want to do `moment.utc(data, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").fromNow()` (untested).  The second argument is telling the moment library how to parse the incoming data